# The last exam would be most likely occurring on?

Tags: probability

Here I have a probability problem: Imagine that you have three exams during the exam week(Monday through Sunday). Each exam is equally likely happening on each of those seven days, and more than one exam can happen on the same day. Which day would the last exam most likely happen on?

Right now I have two approaches, but get different answer. The first one is to use the ordering statistics of uniform distribution on [0, 1]. The expectation of $X_{n}$ is n/(n+1) = 3/4, which tells that the last exam would be most likely on Saturday;

While the second approach is to use the basic combinatorics. There are $7^3$ possibilities in total, and we could calculate the total number of each scenarios. To be specific, if the last exam happens on Sunday, then we have 3*$6^2$(only one exam on Sunday) + 3*6(two exams on Sunday) + 1(three exams on Sunday) = 127 possibilities. In such an approach, I got  answer to be Sunday.

If I change the total samples from 7 to 1000, then Approach 1 seems to be more reasonable. But I just could not figure out where is the mistake in the calculation above.

Comment: There are two *different* questions that you seem to be trying to answer.  The first question you might have tried to answer is "*What is the expected number of days remaining in the week after the final day of testing.*"  The other question is "*What is the day of the week which has the most probability of being the final day of testing.*"  It is important to recognize the difference between these two questions.  If I am interpreting your statements correctly, your first approach tried to answer the first interpretation.  Your second approach tried to answer the second.

Comment: The first essentially asks for a mean (*average*) of a set of data while the second asks for a mode (*most occurring value*).  If you were to be running a simulation to be trying to get evidence supporting a pen and paper approach, firstly 1000 samples is too small.  Secondly, make sure you are using mode, not mean.  The way the question is originally phrased it sounds like the second approach is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks JMoravitz. Just realized the difference between these two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

As @JMoravic said your first approach doesn't answer your question at all.

On the other hand, your second approach is not optimal when you have many examples to count. So you better try this way:

Probability that there were no exams on Sunday is $(\frac 6 7)^3$, probability that there were no exams on Saturday or Sunday is $(\frac 5 7)^3$.

So probability that last exam was on Sunday is $1-(\frac 6 7)^3=\frac{127}{343}$

Probability that last exam was on Saturday is $1-(\frac 5 7)^3-\frac{127}{343}=\frac{91}{343}$

Generally last day has highest probability, you don't have to check it...

Comment: Thanks. I got the point here. Also, thanks for sharing a better way to count for the second approach!

Answer (score 1):

One has
$$P({\rm LD}\leq k)=\left({k\over7}\right)^3\qquad(1\leq k\leq7)$$
and therefore
$$P({\rm LD}= k)=\left({k\over7}\right)^3-\left({k-1\over7}\right)^3={1\over343}(3k^2-3k+1)\qquad(1\leq k\leq7)\ .$$